# Implementing a wildcard search in Google App Engine/Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to implement a basic 'search' system across multiple entities. I know that [there is no like operator support in GQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786/google-app-engine-is-it-possible-to-do-a-gql-like-query), but that leaves with the problem of an efficient, straightforward way of performing searches across my entities.

What is the idiomatic way of performing such searches in Google App Engine/Java ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496023/full-text-search-using-google-app-engine-and-jdo) which suggests Lucene.

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks. Hope to have the change to take a look at it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the [Datastore Java API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/)?

Comment: Sorry, read it already. But maybe I missed the part about 'full-text searches'. Is there such an entry?

Comment: Ok, hadn't understood that you needed full-text searching. Have you looked at http://github.com/ultrasaurus/full-text-search-appengine? Not sure if you were looking at Rails for your framework but even so the approach used here may be of some help in your intended framework

Comment: Actually I need this to work with GAE/Java. In SQL it's pretty simple.

Comment: It is easy in SQL, but the idea of GAE datastore is to scale to force you to make it work on a huge scale (even if you never need that).   That said, are you looking for "starts" with type queries or the ability to specify a wildcard anywhere in the data?